# Integer Decomposition and Squares

Tags: number-theory, integers

I know that every integer $n$ has at least one decomposition into a sum $\sum^t_{i=1} a_i  m_i$ where $m_1,\dots,m_t$ are unique integers and each $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, this decomposition need not to be unique, there may be several. Now suppose I have two distinct decompositions $D_1$ and $D_2$ of the same integer $k$, where $D_1 := \sum^t_{i=1} a_i  m_i$ and $D_2 := \sum^d_{i=1} b_i  n_i$.

Does this imply that $\sum^t_{i=1} a_i  m^2_i \neq \sum^d_{i=1} b_i  n_i^2$? I was wondering because it seems to be true for the case where $k = a_1n_1 = b_1m_1$, but is this true for all decompositions?

Comment: Not clear what you are specifying here.  Are the $m_i$ specified?  If so...suppose they are all even.  How would you write $1$ in that form?

Comment: Just noticed my mistake, every occurrence of integer should be natural positive number, instead. The $m_i$ are supposed to be distinct positive natural numbers. I think the decomposition of $1$ is a special case where $1 = 1*1$ would be the only decomposition. Other than that there are no specifications for $m_i$, they need not be even

Comment: How does your question exclude just writing n = n as the "decomposition" for every n ?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity, as it stands it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.
As a simplification, instead of requiring that $m_i$ are unique (non-negative) integers and $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{N}$, simply think of these as multi-sets)

Find a sufficient condition such that $ \sum w_i = \sum l_i $ and $ \sum w_i^2 = \sum l_i^2$.

> If $ w_i + l_i = N$ a fixed constant, then $ \sum w_i = \sum l_i \Leftrightarrow \sum (w_i - l_i)(w_i+l_i) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum w_i^2 = \sum l_i^2 $.

> Note: This is a "well-known" fact for wins and losses in a round-robin tournament, hence the notation.

In particular, for $ \sum w_i = \frac{ n(n-1)}{2}, n\geq 3$, we can find sets that do not overlap.